# Generating a vector of correlated binary variables in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I'm looking for an efficient O(n) algorithm for creating vectors of correlated binary values, given:

- All values must be identically distributed (though obviously not independent)
- They must have a fixed mean **p**
- They must have a fixed correlation **r** with each other

*e.g.* given **p=0.5** and **r=1.0** I would expect vectors **[0 0 0 ...]** and **[1 1 1 ...]** to be generated with equal probability. But with **p=0.5** and **r=0.0** I would expect the binary values to be independent fair coin tosses.

Because the algorithm must run in O(n) time, any solution that involves generating a correlation matrix is automatically ruled out.

Is there any simple algorithm that can achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "correlation"?  The Pearson correlation coefficient?  But this can be as low as -1 (perfect anticorrelation) -- and in that case it is not possible to have 3 perfectly anticorrelated binary variables (since the first two must always be either 0 and 1 or vice versa, and the third variable must be equal to one of them).

Comment: I was thinking Pearson correlation... though if there is a better measure of correlation for this use case then happy to consider it. I recognise that some correlation values may be impossible

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that for 3 or more binary variables, it might be that the *only* Pearson correlation coefficients that are achievable between all pairs of variables are 0 and 1...

Comment: Hmmm if you first generate a value y in range [0..1] with mean p and then generate all the binary values with probability y you definitely get correlated binary values with mean p. I think the problem boils down to how to generate y to guarantee correlation r...